# Hard custom tag in carl bot (discord)

Tags: discord

Yes - im gonna make a app/server on discord (game-themed). One of things which’ll be there is just sharing games, etc. One command i wanted to make’d be that someone can send linked game to specified channel with some other variables also. As i like carl (for the now it’s the only bot i use? :/ ) i’m just gonna use this. I read some things about tags i think. I created some non-working code but i just want to make it work, not only have some text. Here is this bugged plain-text : `{redirect:{args(1)}} {embed(title):{args(2)}} {embed(URL):{args(3)} {embed(description):{args(+4)}}{embed(color):#0000ff}{embed(timestamp):now}`  does somebody know why it doesn’t work? Where is mistake? Or im thinking wrong? Thx for answer.
Here is preview of this bug:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBj7e.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing curly bracket at the end of your `{embed(url)}` block:

Should be:

```
{embed(URL):{args(3)}}
```

Comment: thank you. maybe i left already this project and focused on making my own bot but i think it can be just useful for others =]